# Changing description of image in python-pptx

Tags: python, image, powerpoint, python-pptx

Does anyone know a way to change the description of a pictureShape in python-pptx,

something like `img._pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.get('descr')` but for setting the description like `img._pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.set('descr')`.

Answer (score 1):

Found this `img._pic.nvPicPr.cNvPr.set('descr', newPic)` and it seemed to work